# HP laptop not turning on?

Tags: laptop-repair

My HP laptop G42 is 3 years old. And it was working fine this morning. Switched it off normally, and later when I tried to turn on, it didn't. I read on HP support forum to remove the Battery and hold on power button for 30 secs, put battery back and plug in charger. I tried that and it didn't work. Not even the charging indicator light is showing, no sound, nothing. What could be the problem? And it had overheating problem.

Comment: If it overheated its entirely possible it has caused damage to your laptop.  Why didn't you fix the overheating problem?  Laptops don't overheat if they are working properly.

Comment: Well there was construction work going.. before that it didn't have overheat problem.. I thought to take care of it once the construction work is done. But it happened this way!

Comment: Well considering the construction work, you could very easily have gotten dust and other debris, such as metal, into places where it should not be so we can only speculate as to what is wrong. If for example a shard of tiny metal got sucked into your laptop and made contact with the motherboard then it could have easily caused a short-circuit and fried your motherboard. If my theory is true then it would explain why you have no lights, no sound, no nothing.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to open it up, clean the dust out, and see if you can see any damage. If something did get sucked into the case, and there was a short that happen, there is nothing you can do about it at this point if there actually is damage.

Comment: Can you remove the battery totallly, plug the laptop in and start it up? Does that do anything?  Are you sure the cable itself is working?

Comment: @monkeyzeus that is the worst scenario I'm thinking off! :'(

Comment: @ramhound would take it a center, that way I won't cause more damage..

Comment: @daverook tried it, nothing happened! :-/

Comment: @Nina This is a really sucky situation to have a broken laptop but if the hard drive wasn't short-circuited and still functional then it is a very easy process to recover your files, photos, etc...

Comment: @monkeyzeus it sucks big time not knowing what would happen.. fingers crossed.. :|

Comment: Are you sure the charger/cable is OK? I mean, did it ever have a light to indicate it was on or similar?

Comment: @daverook yep. Orange while charging. White when fully charged. Decided to take it to the help center!